# React, como instalarlo

Tags: reactjs

Estoy empezando un curso y ando tratando de desplegar react en mi vs code. Ya tengo node instalado. Me dijeron que tenía que editar las variables de entorno; ayer le pregunté a chat gpt por el tema y me hizo hacer un archivo .env con una variable dentro, pero sigo sin poder desplegar React, al menos con Vite. Ya reinstalé varias veces Node.

Todo el código siguiente es mi gitbash:

```bash
lauta@DESKTOP-038INHV MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ node -v
v18.18.0

lauta@DESKTOP-038INHV MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ npm -v
10.2.0

lauta@DESKTOP-038INHV MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

lauta@DESKTOP-038INHV MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

lauta@DESKTOP-038INHV MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ npm create vite@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js
npm ERR! path C:\Users\lauta\Desktop
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\lauta\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-09T16_45_41_799Z-debug-0.log

lauta@DESKTOP-038INHV MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que problema tuviste al instalar react?

Comment: ¿Está NodeJS en tus variables de entorno de Windows?

Comment: No se si acá se responde. Si, ya modifiqué las variables de entorno con las rutas a la carpeta raiz de node y npm

Comment: Proba este comando y entra en la carpeta que te crea en el visual, luego seguí los pasos que te da en consola npm create vite@latest react-project

Comment: sigue tirando error, mirá: $ npm create vite@latest react-project
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js      
npm ERR! path C:\Users\lauta\Desktop\APRENDIENDO REACT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Comment: Ok. Lo pregunto porque me parece llamativa esta línea de error: `npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js`. Esa ruta generalmente es para los accesos directos...

Comment: ¿Revisaste qué dice el log que te está mostrando el mensaje de error?

Comment: Igual  capaz me falta hacer algo y en mi desconocimiento no lo sé, Yo edité las variables de entorno que me da windows en la configuración, le consulté a chat gpt tambien y me hizo hacer un archivo .env con esta variable  REACT_APP_PORT=3000
export PATH=c:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: Revisé lo que dice en log y hasta mi carpeta lauta todo bien, ya el AppData no existe  en la carpeta lauta, al menos no al pie de la letra

Comment: Intenta esto npm install -g npm y volve a tirar el comando, puede ser que npm no se este instalando como se deberia

Comment: Sinceramente no sé cuál sea el problema. Probé ejecutando `npm create vite@latest` en cmd y git bash, con la versión 9.8.1 y la 10.2.0 y no obtengo ningún error.

Comment: Porque estas tratando de ejecutar esto sobre el escritorio, y no sobre una carpeta comun?

Comment: estoy haciendolo en el escritorio por que estoy haciendo un curso de React y eso está en el inicio